# NamingException over domain name JAVA

Tags: java

I have a list with domains. When I iterate over this list I get domains mx records. If the domain is invalid try catch block throws NamingException and iterating over the list stops. How to continue program execution after throwing a name exception ?

```
  try {

                logger(clazz, "job started");

                List<Domain> domains = new ArrayList<>();
                domains.addAll(domManager.getActiveDoms());

                for (Domain d : domains) {
                    Attributes attributes = iDirC.getAttributes("dns:/" + d.getName(), new String[] { "MX" });
                    Attribute attributeMX = attributes.get("MX");
                    System.out.println(attributes);
                }

            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has an try-catch block with a loop inside it, that way, if something fails, the program will abort (because of `e.printStackTrace()`). 
Note that you said "(...) after throwing a name exception" and that is not what is happening! In order to throw an exception, you have to use `throw new NamingException("cause");` and have a `throws NamingException` in your method's declaration.

Now, answering your question:
If you handle the error inside the loop, you can continue (note that if you have `e.printStackTrace()` the program will still end there).

I would do something like:

```
logger(clazz, "job started");

List<Domain> domains = new ArrayList<>();
domains.addAll(domManager.getActiveDoms());

for (Domain d : domains) {
    try {
        Attributes attributes = iDirC.getAttributes("dns:/" + d.getName(), new String[] { "MX" });
        Attribute attributeMX = attributes.get("MX");
        System.out.println(attributes);

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        //do somethig here like `System.out.println("error message!");`
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you!